Retrieve metadata for "Platform Integration User" profile in Apex Class security for automation
I am tasked to disable profiles in some apex class security. This includes the "Platform Integration User". If I could disable it in the image below, I should be able to disable it in Metadata API (see this and this), and use it for automation. Since the 2 links don't cover this, my question is how can I disable this profile thru Metadata API? Is this even possible?


You can not change this per class using the metadata api. But you can use the metadata api to retrieve and deploy profiles.
Salesforce doesn't include data in profiles while retrieving if the referenced record is not also retrieved at the same time. So to retrieve you should use
sf project retrieve start -m Profile -m ApexClass. Then you can edit the classAccess in the profiles and deploy them again.

Thanks for the answer. I am aware of that. Now I tried sf project retrieve start -m "Profile:Platform Integration User" -m "ApexClass:..." ... --target-metadata-dir ... but the result is empty ZIP except the metadata xml (but no errors). Maybe I am missing something.

To retrieve a profile you need to use the FullName column from the profile instead of the Name. Sadly the platform integration profile seems to be hidden. The Id can be found when querying users, but querying the Profile with that Id returns nothing.

Yeah I am now thinking that this is not possible for Platform Integration User profile.
